# Unlike not performed even on FB Like Button code generator page

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I'm trying to implement FB Like button on my wordpress blog pages. So I successfully created a basic FB application. Placed the correct og: tags in my header:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.65colors.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/cropped-Rose-Header-Section-1-and-Size-31.jpg" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="119418934882292" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:description" content="כל צבעי הורדים" />
<?php if(is_home()) {
 ?><meta property="og:title" content="כל צבעי הורדים" /><?php
 } else {
 ?><meta property="og:title" content="<?php the_title_attribute( $args ); ?>" /><?php
 }
 ?>
 <?php if (is_home())
 echo '<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.65colors.co.il" />';
 else echo '<meta property="og:url" content="'.get_permalink().'" />';
 ?>
```

And other add-ons FB require (especially the JS). Now Object Debugger sees my page correctly (no warnings/errors/etc.). I implemented the following code to place the Like button:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" data-width="90" data-height="20" data-    colorscheme="light" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-    send="false"></div>
```

Basically, the code came from FB Like Button code generator page. Although everything seems fine, I have 2 issues:

1. On like, nothing is posted to user's timeline.
2. On unlike, Like button counts 1 down – but after a refresh, it appears as I still like this page.

I noticed similar (to 2) behavior on some other blogs across the web!

And the same misbehavior happens even on FB  Like button code generator page itself! Say, I asked to generate a code for http://www.65colors.co.il/?p=3095 , At the bottom you can see how it's going to look – BUT even here, directly on facebook – both issues happen.
Any thoughts and suggestions will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: The same happens both for HTML5 and IFrame Like button code.

Comment: like plugin only works with absolute urls so having this  http://www.65colors.co.il/?p=3095 or this  http://www.65colors.co.il/ it's the same

Comment: Hello Fabio,

Thank you for answering. Though it's not directly related to the issues described above, can you please be more specific on what do you mean by plugin?

Since, different pages on my website have already different number of 'likes'; hence I do assume each URL within a site has different counter assigned to it.

Anyhow, the issues above remain unsolved. Even on www.facebook.com.